# Simple Bash script loop

Tags: bash, loops, nested

I want to use bash script to generate some files. The file names will be in the format 2_x.yRandom.txt, where x is 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 and y is from 1 to 5.
eg. "2_2.2Random.txt" or  "2_4.3Random.txt"

This is my script:

```
#Generate input for sort1
for i in 2 4 6 8 10
do
    for j in 1 2 3 4 5
    do
        java utils.StringGenerator r 2 $i > "2_$i.$jRandom.txt" 
        java utils.StringGenerator s 2 $i > "2_$i.$jSorted.txt 
        java utils.StringGenerator v 2 $i > "2_$i.$jReversed.txt 
    done
done
```

The output file is always 2_2..txt or 2_4..txt, it seems that $j is not in the output.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
PS: I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to tell bash where the variable name ends.

```
    java utils.StringGenerator r 2 $i > "2_$i.${j}Random.txt"
```